# Can't properly stop SAP Hana on reboot / shutdown with systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, startup, shutdown

We encountered the following problem in our company. We have multiple Red Hat Enterprise Linux Servers on which "SAP HANA S/4" is running. 
We created a systemd Service to automatically start and stop the daemon so that we don't need to manually interact with the system on a reboot or shutdown.

Autostart works well, but there seems to be a problem with stopping the daemon correctly on shutdown. The daemons are running with another user (individual for each server). It seems that systemd starts to kill the user sessions before the actual service is stopped; as a result, the service won't stop properly.

**Service**

```
[Unit]
Description=saphana
After=remote-fs.target user.slice sapinit.service multi-user.target
Requires=user.slice

[Service]
KillMode=none
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/hana/source/scripts/sapHanaControl.pl start
ExecStop=/hana/source/scripts/sapHanaControl.pl stop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script wich is called in ExecStart and ExecStop basically executes the following command.

**On Start:**

```
"sudo -u $username csh -c "sapcontrol -nr $instance -function Start"
```

**On Stop:**
    "sudo -u $username csh -c "sapcontrol -nr $instance -function Stop"

**Shutdown log**

Output of the Systemd Log shows the following:

```
Jun 20 16:23:05 host123 systemd[1]: Stopping Session c4 of user **userxy**.
Jun 20 16:23:05 host123sapHanaControl.pl[15003]: sudo -u **userxy** csh -c "sapcontrol -nr 00 -function Stop"
Jun 20 16:23:05 host123 sapHanaControl.pl[15003]: 20.06.2018 16:23:05
Jun 20 16:23:05 host123 sapHanaControl.pl[15003]: Stop
Jun 20 16:23:05 host123 sapHanaControl.pl[15003]: FAIL: NIECONN_REFUSED (Connection refused), NiRawConnect failed in plugin_fopen()
```

**Update**

I see the following processes running when the system is running normally:

```
[root@wsstadt325 ~]# ps -ef | grep sapstartsrv
d61adm    1740     1  0 11:56 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sap/D61/HDB05/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/usr/sap/D61/SYS/profile/D61_HDB05_wsstadt325 -D -u d61adm
sapadm    1741     1  0 11:56 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/host_profile -D
d21adm    1946     1  0 11:56 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sap/D21/ASCS01/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/usr/sap/D21/SYS/profile/D21_ASCS01_wsstadt325 -D -u d21adm
d21adm    2182     1  0 11:56 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sap/D21/D00/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/usr/sap/D21/SYS/profile/D21_D00_wsstadt325 -D -u d21adm`
```

Chnaged my script to log the "ps -ef | grep sapstartsrv" output when the system gets rebooted / powered off.

```
ps -ef | grep sapstartsrv
sapadm    1683     1  0 13:52 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/host_profile -D
root      5706  5522  0 14:00 ?        00:00:00 sh -c ps -ef | grep sapstartsrv
root      5708  5706  0 14:00 ?        00:00:00 grep sapstartsrv
```

The sapstartsrv Service is started by a default SAP Service (sapinit) wich gets startet before my own Systemd Service (So on a reboot it is the reversed order [Stop my Systemd Service -> stop the Sapinit Service]) The problem seems to be that systemctl starts to kill the user session (In my case for the user: d21adm and d61adm) where the sapstartsrv process is running before my actual Systemd service is stopped. (Hope that makes at least a bit sense)

Here's an image of the whole systemd chain (my services are at the very end):
The services involved:
- sapinit.service (The default one)
- saphana.service (My custom one)

[image: Image Systemd Chain]

Comment: what if you manually try to stop `sapcontrol`? Does the error occur as well?

Comment: I've found an article, which indicates that NiRawConnect error can occur if `sapstartsrv` service isn't running while stopping `sapcontrol`.
Check it out here: https://blogs.sap.com/2015/09/07/how-to-solve-nieconnrefused-issues-during-sapcontrol-execution/

Comment: Manually stopping the `sapcotrol` works well. The error just occours on a reboot or shutdown of the system.  As you found out the problem seems to be with the `sapstartsrv` service wich in my case is running under a differen user. (Will edit my queston with the new infomation) @sys463

Comment: Under which user are you running the systemd unit?

Comment: Both systemd units are running as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the cause of my problem as described in the following KB
https://www.suse.com/de-de/support/kb/doc/?id=7022671

Systemd kills every user.slice after 90 seconds (This timeout can't be changed) It looks like systemd just isn't made to automatically Stop SAP HANA Instances without modifying pam.d. The Solution described there seems to be a bit "hackish" but it works.

```
cp /etc/pam.d/system-auth /etc/pam.d/custom-su-session
vim /etc/pam.d/custom-su-session
```

Insert the following line before "session optional pam_systemd.so"

`session [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=ok default=ignore] pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow file=/etc/custom-su-session`

This line skips the user.slice creation when the su command is executed an the user is listed in the file /etc/custom-su-session

```
vim /etc/pam.d/su
```

Replace `session include system-auth`
with `session include custom-su-session`